# asp.net core web api returns 500 server error

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, swagger, azure-web-app-service, ef-core-2.0

I am new to asp.net Web API. I am using EF Core to work with data. I have two tables in SQL Server, `USER_DATA` and `WORK_DATA`.

I am trying to send HTTP GET request and fetch data from `WORK_DATA` table, but the response is a 500 error and says no content. I can Get and Post completely to `USER_DATA`. I could not only fetch `WORK_DATA`. I think that routing is correct and the struct of  SQL Server's table  s wrong but I do not know how to fix it.

SQL Server struct is here: the database has two tables `USER_DATA` and `WORK_DATA`:

`USER_DATA` has these columns

```
Id (PK, varchar, notnull)
UserName (varchar, null)
RegisterDate (Date, null)
Field (varchar, null)
Password (varchar, null)
Heats (int, null)
```

`WORK_DATA` has these columns

```
WorkId (PK, varchar, notnull)
WorkName (varchar, null)
Detailinformation (varchar, null)
Salary (varchar, null)
Worklength (varchar, null)
Reliability (int, null)
RegisterDate (date, null)
isCompleted (bit, null)
Id (varchar, not null)
```

Foreign key is `Id` and it reference `USER_DATA.Id`.

Models are here - `Item` corresponds to `USER_DATA` in SQL Server, `Workdata` corresponds to `WORK_DATA`.

**Item**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace NewHeats.Models
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
        public string Field { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set;}
        public int Heats { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Workdata**:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using     System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace NewHeats.Models
{
    public class Workdata
    {
        public string WorkId { get; set; }
        public string WorkName { get; set; }
        public string DetailInformation { get; set; }
        public string Salary { get; set; }
        public string Worklength { get; set; }
        public int Reliability { get; set; }
        public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
        public int isCompleted { get; set; }

        public string Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Id")]
        public Item Item { get; set; }
     }
}
```

DbContext:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace NewHeats.Models
{
    public class ItemRepository : DbContext ,IItemRepository
    {
        public ItemRepository(DbContextOptions<ItemRepository> options)
        : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating (ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            try
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<Item>(entity =>
                {
                    entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
                    entity.ToTable("USER_DATA");
                });

                modelBuilder.Entity<Workdata>(entity =>
                {
                    entity.HasKey(e => e.WorkId);
                    entity.ToTable("WORK_DATA");
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Item> USER_DATA { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Workdata> WORK_DATA { get; set; }

        public Item Get(string id)
        {
            return USER_DATA.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Item> GetAll()
        {
            return USER_DATA.ToList();
        }

        public void Add(Item item)
        {
            item.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            USER_DATA.Add(item);
        }

        public Item Find(string id)
        {
            return USER_DATA.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==id);
        }

        public Item Remove(string id)
        {
            return USER_DATA.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        }

        public void Update(Item item)
        {
            USER_DATA.Remove(USER_DATA.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.Id));
            USER_DATA.Add(item);
        }

        public Workdata GetWorkdata(string workId)
        {
            return WORK_DATA.FirstOrDefault(x => x.WorkId == workId);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Workdata> GetAllWorkdata()
        {
            return this.WORK_DATA.ToList();
        }

        public void AddWorkdata(Workdata workdata)
        {
            workdata.WorkId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            WORK_DATA.Add(workdata);
        }

        public Workdata FindWorkdata(string workId)
        {
            return WORK_DATA.FirstOrDefault(x => x.WorkId == workId);
        }

        public Workdata RemoveWorkdata(string workId)
        {
            return WORK_DATA.FirstOrDefault(x => x.WorkId == workId);
        }

        public void UpdateWorkdata(Workdata workdata)
        {
            WORK_DATA.Remove(WORK_DATA.FirstOrDefault(x => x.WorkId == workdata.WorkId));
            WORK_DATA.Add(workdata);
        }
    }
}
```

**IItemRepository**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace NewHeats.Models
{
    public interface IItemRepository
    {
        void Add(Item item);
        void Update(Item item);
        Item Remove(string key);
        Item Get(string id);
        IEnumerable<Item> GetAll();
        void AddWorkdata(Workdata workdata);
        void UpdateWorkdata(Workdata workdata);
        Workdata RemoveWorkdata(string workid);
        Workdata GetWorkdata(string workid);
        IEnumerable<Workdata> GetAllWorkdata();
    }
}
```

Controllers are here

**ItemController**

Corresponds to my USER_DATA table in SQL Server

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

using NewHeats.Models;

namespace NewHeats.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ItemController : Controller
    {
        private ItemRepository _itemRepository;

        public ItemController(ItemRepository itemRepository)
        {
            _itemRepository = itemRepository;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult List()
        {           
            return Ok(_itemRepository.GetAll());
        }

        [HttpGet("{Id}")]
        public Item GetItem(string id)
        {
            Item item = _itemRepository.Get(id);
            return item;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create([FromBody]Item item)
        {
            try
            {
                if (item == null || !ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest("Invalid State");
                }

                _itemRepository.Add(item);
                _itemRepository.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return BadRequest("Error while creating");
            }
            return Ok(item);
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public IActionResult Edit([FromBody] Item item)
        {
            try
            {
                if (item == null || !ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest("Invalid State");
                }

                _itemRepository.Update(item);
                 _itemRepository.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return BadRequest("Error while creating");
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        [HttpDelete("{Id}")]
        public void Delete(string id)
        {
            _itemRepository.Remove(id);
            _itemRepository.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

**WorkdataController**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using NewHeats.Models;

namespace NewHeats.MobileAppService.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class WorkdataController :Controller
    {
        private ItemRepository _itemRepository;

        public WorkdataController(ItemRepository itemRepository)
        {
            _itemRepository = itemRepository;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult List()
        {
             return Ok(_itemRepository.GetAllWorkdata());
        }

        [HttpGet("{WorkId}")]
        public Workdata GetItem(string workId)
        {
            Workdata workdata = _itemRepository.GetWorkdata(workId);
            return workdata;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create([FromBody]Workdata workdata)
        {
            try
            {
                if (workdata == null || !ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest("Invalid State");
                }

                _itemRepository.AddWorkdata(workdata);
                _itemRepository.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                return BadRequest("Error while creating");
            }
            return Ok(workdata);
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public IActionResult Edit([FromBody] Workdata workdata)
        {
            try
            {
                if (workdata == null || !ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest("Invalid State");
                }

                _itemRepository.UpdateWorkdata(workdata);
                _itemRepository.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return BadRequest("Error while creating");
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        [HttpDelete("{WorkId}")]
        public void Delete(string workId)
        {
            _itemRepository.RemoveWorkdata(workId);
            _itemRepository.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to solve this problem a week but I could not. I searched a lot of stackoverflow , msdn etc... Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: error 500 means that something is wrong with the code. its good that you have posted the code. however.. do you know where the error is? have you take a peek on event viewer (`eventvwr.msc`)?

Comment: To Bagus Tesa I actually do not know where is the problem but I guess that GetAllWorkdata method in ItemRepository class has a problem that WORK_DATA is null so cannot ToList(). I am using Mac so I cannot use eventvwr.msc.

Comment: Check what is the exception that leads to that `500`, run with debugger and break on exceptions.

Comment: To Ofiris, thanks for your comment. I checked and the exception says no contents. I use websites and already deployed so I could not find exception and could not put break points. I tested on useInMemory and no exception occurred. Do you have other idea?

Comment: @NaotoMunekiyo sorry for assuming your environment. but it is real hard to know what happens at runtime without logs or debugger.. could you check on whatever log MacOS has (e.g. Console - View - Show Log List)? the only possibility i could think of is that your DI is not loaded so that it got null.. but thats very unlikely. `public virtual DbSet<Workdata> WORK_DATA { get; set; }` going null also impossible as you extend `DbContext`.

Comment: To Bagus Tesa, thanks for your help. I actually use azure DB so I do not know how to get Log List from azure database. Do you have any idea to get Log List from azure DB?

Comment: To Bagus Tesa  I also think my DI is not loaded but I do not know how to fix it.WORK_DATA table can POST data and sql server also correctly create a new data. WORK_Data table cannot only GET data.

Comment: @NaotoMunekiyo If you use [Logging in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging) that'll help you troubleshoot errors in your remote site.  Then add try/catch around `List()` like you did for `Create()` & `Edit()`.

Comment: To Mark G where does my web api write log after I deployed the web api?

Comment: @NaotoMunekiyo That depends on how you configured your web API. For instance if you have something along the lines of `loggerFactory.AddConsole()` then errors are logged to the console. 
Currently .NET Core does not have inbuilt support for logging to a file, but you might consult the open issue at [aspnet/Logging/issues/441](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/441) if you want to log to a file by i.e. using a third part Logging library like `Log4Net`

Comment: @NaotoMunekiyo For simple file logging, take a look at [Serilog.Sinks.File](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file).